# Cron formula for every Sunday 00:01:00 and Saturday 23:59:00

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml

We need to set 2 formulas for AWS Lambda :

1) Every Saturday 23:59:00

```
schedule: cron(0 59 23 ? * SAT *)
```

2) At 00:01:00am, on every Sunday, every month

```
schedule: cron(0 1 0 ? * SUN *)
```

We put both in the YAML file however they didn't trigger (but worked manually).

How can I verify their correctness ?

Comment: What do you mean by "We put both in the YAML file"? Are you referring to CloudFormation? Can you show it in your question? What timezone were you wanting to use for those times?

Comment: Use this tool to verify cron expressions http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what is wrong without viewing your Cloudformation template, but your yml file should resemble something like this:

```
functions:   test:
    handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
    description: "test serverless Lambda"
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 300
    events:
      - schedule:
        rate: cron(59 23 ? * SAT *)
        enabled: true
        input:
          key: value
      - schedule:
        rate: cron(00 01 ? * Sun *)
        input: '{"key": "value"}'
        enabled: true
```

Comment: As for "Verifying their correctness", i assume you mean you want to test that cron event actually triggers the lambda. You should just edit the cron value to trigger once a minute, or set up a test lambda function to verify that this works before pushing the stack. Just be aware that the cron times are UTC.

Comment: Thanks , but where in the console can I change the timezone ?

Comment: So Cloudwatch cron events do not currently support timezones outside of UTC, you will either need offset your cron expression by the time difference, or it you are using the serverless framework, there is a plugin for this... https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-local-schedule

Comment: What is `input: '{"key": "value"}'` ? Do I need it really ?

Comment: No, that was just to show how you could provide an input event to your lambda function trigger. Not required.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `cron(59 23 ? * SAT *)` and remember the timezone cron uses is GMT. You have to set the GMT time that matches your timezone.

For sunday one it should be `cron(00 01 ? * Sun *)`.

A cron event for lambda is basically a cloudwatch event. You can view the correctness of your cron in the cloudwatch event itself. it will show you the next 10 occurrences of the cron as you modify it.

Hope this helps. good luck